# Is there anything inherently dangerous about letting users update a div with their own HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a page for kids to explain some of the basics of how HTML works, and one of the things I wanted to do was add a feature for them to enter a tag and have it rendered by the browser, in real time.

I know there are lots of websites that already do this, but I couldn't find one that could be embedded on my site, or was simple enough anyway. The solution I came up with is pretty simple...

```js
function update() {
  var sandbox = document.getElementById("sandbox");
  var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
  sandbox.innerHTML = editor.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <textarea id="editor" style="width:100%; height: auto;" placeholder="Try typing some HTML here" maxlength="100" oninput="update()"></textarea>
    <div id="sandbox" style="width:100%; height: auto;"></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I can't think of anything that would be inherently dangerous about this, since users can basically already do this sort of thing in the console and it's client side. But I just wanted to double check and make sure I wasn't creating a vulnerability in my site or doing something not so great. Sorry if this is a silly question and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can allow for arbitrary code execution:

```js
function update() {
  var sandbox = document.getElementById("sandbox");
  var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
  sandbox.innerHTML = editor.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <textarea id="editor" style="width:100%; height: auto;" placeholder="Try typing some HTML here" maxlength="100" oninput="update()"></textarea>
    <div id="sandbox" style="width:100%; height: auto;"></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Enter in `<img src onerror="alert('evil')">` to see.

This may be an issue if the user has any ability to store personal information on the site (such as a login). Then, all a malicious actor needs to be able to do to steal that information is to convince someone to paste in untrustworthy code.

(This same sort of attack is the reason why many websites display big warnings to users when the browser console gets opened - they often say something like "If something told you to paste code in here, DO NOT DO SO, it is a scam attempt to steal your information.")

A possible solution is to embed the result in a sandboxed iframe, the way Stack Snippets and JSFiddle and Codepen and other sites work - if done properly, this ensures that anything done inside the iframe cannot get out of the sandbox and access important information outside the iframe in the parent page.

If there is no chance of personal information being entered into or stored anywhere through the website, then setting arbitrary HTML is probably safe - worst-case, if the site becomes inoperable, the user just needs to reload the page. (But using a sandboxed iframe anyway is a good idea)

Comment: Interesting, I'm glad I asked. I've never heard of anything like that before, but how would the attacks work exactly? The only thing I could think of before was that it might be possible for someone to write an AJAX script. Funnily enough, I found the iframe sandbox attribute while I was looking for an "HTML sandbox," but I only glanced over it. I'll take a closer look, since it sounds like the way to go.

Comment: For example, the malicious script could retrieve the cookies and/or localStorage, and then send it out to the malicious server.

Comment: I see. Cookies didn’t even cross my mind. Makes sense, thanks!